# Ionic 2 - ion-list component hides second item in Android platform

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

My home page looks like below.

[image]

My home page html code is as below.

```
<ion-content class="background">
  <p class="page-title">Talker</p>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
     Login
    </ion-card-header>
     <ion-card-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item active>
            <ion-input type="item" placeholder="Username"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item active>
            <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <a class="right-align-text">Forgot Password</a>        
        <button ion-button block outline color="light"><p>OR</p></button>          
        <button ion-button block facebook color="facebook">
              <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"> </ion-icon> Login With Facebook
        </button>
      </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Now, when I run the code, I am not able to enter the 'Password' detail. If I click on Password field, the page automatically looks like below.

[image]

### My CSS file

```
page-home {
.background{
    background-image : url('../assets/bg.jpg');
}
.page-title{
    text-align : center;
    font-family: 'Ravi Prakash', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    color : snow;
}
.left-align-text{
    text-align : left;
    align-content : left;
    justify-content : left;
    float : left;
}
.right-align-text{
    text-align : right;
    align-content : right;   
    justify-content : right;
    float : right;
}
a{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.link-text{
    color : blue;
}
.scroll-content{
    align-content : top;
    display : flex;
    flex-direction : column;
    justify-content : top;
    text-align : top;
}

.login-card{
    background : lightpink;
    border-radius : 10px;
}

.login-card ion-item{
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-bottom : 5px;
}

.orbutton{
    width : 10%;
    position : relative;
    left : 40%;  
    margin : 10px;
}
}
```

This happens only on Android platform. When I choose to run the same code in IOS platform, everything works fine. 
Can Someone please help me regarding this?

Comment: Are you modifying the .scroll-content class in your scss file..?

Comment: Yes. I have edited my question with the .scss file.

Comment: Remove the scroll-content modification and try it and let us know if it works fine..

Comment: When I remove it, the hiding problem is resolved. But the second field 'password' goes down the display screen. So that, I should all the way scroll down (using the vertical scroll bar that automatically appears) to see it atleast.